# JavaFX setPrefSize is not changing vBox size

Tags: java, javafx, layout, netbeans

I am very beginner at JavaFX and im facing this issue:
I want to make layout like this: [What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYot0.png)

And this is what i have: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWuMa.png)

It seems that i tried a lot of different layouts and i just cant get it right. I ended up with VBox'es and thats the best i can get. Even though I described "vBox2" size with "PrefSize" to be Half Half of the whole scene, it doesnt react at all.

This is my code:

```
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create a border pane
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

         // Place nodes in the pane
        pane.setLeft(getVBox());
        pane.setBottom(getVBox2());
        pane.setRight(getVBox3());

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1000,800);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowHBoxVBox"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    private VBox getVBox() {
        VBox vBox = new VBox(15);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("vbox"));

        Label[] courses = {new Label("CSCI 1301"), new Label("CSCI 1302"),
            new Label("CSCI 2410"), new Label("CSCI 3720")};

        for (Label course : courses) {
            VBox.setMargin(course, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 15));
            vBox.getChildren().add(course);
        }
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
        vBox.setPrefSize(500, 400);

        return vBox;
    }

    private VBox getVBox2() {
        VBox vBox2 = new VBox(15);
        vBox2.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox2.getChildren().add(new Label("Vbox2"));

        Label[] courses = {new Label("CSCI 1301"), new Label("CSCI 1302"),
            new Label("CSCI 2410"), new Label("CSCI 3720")};

        for (Label course : courses) {
            VBox.setMargin(course, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 15));
            vBox2.getChildren().add(course);
        }
        vBox2.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
        vBox2.setPrefSize(500, 400);

        return vBox2;
    }

    private VBox getVBox3() {
        VBox vBox3 = new VBox(15);
        vBox3.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox3.getChildren().add(new Label("vbox3"));

        Label[] courses = {new Label("CSCI 1301"), new Label("CSCI 1302"),
            new Label("CSCI 2410"), new Label("CSCI 3720")};

        for (Label course : courses) {
            VBox.setMargin(course, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 15));
            vBox3.getChildren().add(course);
        }
        vBox3.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
        vBox3.setPrefSize(500, 800);

        return vBox3;
    }

}
```

I cant use FXML or style it in CSS.

Thank you for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general process for a layout pane (such as `VBox` or `BorderPane`) to layout its child nodes is as follows:

1. Query the child nodes for their minimum, maximum, and preferred
   sizes
2. Compute the position and size to be allocated to each child
   node, adhering to its own layout policy, and making a best effort to
   respect the minimum, preferred, and maximum sizes of the child nodes
3. Request the child nodes perform their own layout, allocating the
   sizes calculated to each

It's not always possible to respect all the min/max/pref constraints of the child nodes; e.g. if the sum of the minimum heights of all children of a `VBox` is greater than the height of the `VBox` itself, there's simply no way to fit all the children in the layout. Conversely, if the height of the `VBox` is greater than the sum of all the preferred heights of the children, there will be extra vertical space to be allocated somehow. Most layout panes have settings that configure how to handle these situations: some of these settings apply to the entire layout pane, others are applied on a per-child basis.

The layout policy for a `BorderPane` is essentially as follows:

- The `top` and `bottom` nodes are allocated the full width of the `BorderPane`, and each get their preferred height. These nodes are positioned across the full width of the border pane, at the top and bottom respectively. **This is the part that makes the `BorderPane` behave differently to the way you require.**
- The `left` and `right` nodes are allocated the full height of the `BorderPane`, less the height of the `top` and `bottom` nodes, and each get their preferred width. These are positioned at the left and right of the border pane, respectively, below the `top` and above the `bottom` nodes.
- The `center` node receives all the remaining space.

This is adjusted if the resulting sizes violate minimum or maximum sizes of the nodes, if possible.

So the layout in your image is exactly as expected; `vbox2` gets the full width and its preferred height; `vbox` gets its preferred width and the remaining height of the border pane, and `vbox3` gets the remaining space.

You can basically achieve what you're looking for here by placing `vbox` and `vbox2` in a `VBox` of their own, and placing that `VBox` in the left of the border pane; then placing `vbox3` in the center (the right would work too):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Layout extends Application {
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create a border pane
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

         // Place nodes in the pane

        VBox left = new VBox(getVBox(), getVBox2());
        pane.setLeft(left);
        pane.setCenter(getVBox3());

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowHBoxVBox"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    private VBox getVBox() {
        VBox vBox = new VBox(15);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("vbox"));

        Label[] courses = {new Label("CSCI 1301"), new Label("CSCI 1302"),
            new Label("CSCI 2410"), new Label("CSCI 3720")};

        for (Label course : courses) {
            VBox.setMargin(course, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 15));
            vBox.getChildren().add(course);
        }
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
        vBox.setPrefSize(500, 400);

        return vBox;
    }

    private VBox getVBox2() {
        VBox vBox2 = new VBox(15);
        vBox2.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox2.getChildren().add(new Label("Vbox2"));

        Label[] courses = {new Label("CSCI 1301"), new Label("CSCI 1302"),
            new Label("CSCI 2410"), new Label("CSCI 3720")};

        for (Label course : courses) {
            VBox.setMargin(course, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 15));
            vBox2.getChildren().add(course);
        }
        vBox2.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
        vBox2.setPrefSize(500, 400);

        return vBox2;
    }

    private VBox getVBox3() {
        VBox vBox3 = new VBox(15);
        vBox3.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox3.getChildren().add(new Label("vbox3"));

        Label[] courses = {new Label("CSCI 1301"), new Label("CSCI 1302"),
            new Label("CSCI 2410"), new Label("CSCI 3720")};

        for (Label course : courses) {
            VBox.setMargin(course, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 15));
            vBox3.getChildren().add(course);
        }
        vBox3.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
        vBox3.setPrefSize(500, 800);

        return vBox3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }

}
```

You haven't specified how you want this to behave on resizing the window, but the "center" region will essentially be more "responsive" than the left.

The initial window looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem I can think of it to construct two HBox and place the VBox inside of them. 
For an example on how: Sebastian Damm created this simple one:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/javafx-20-layout-panes-hbox-and-vbox.html

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 *
 * Created on: 20.03.2012
 * @author Sebastian Damm
 */
public class HBoxandVBoxExample extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {                
        HBox hbox = new HBox(50);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); // default TOP_LEFT

        VBox vbox1 = new VBox();
        vbox1.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        vbox1.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
                + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
                + "-fx-border-color: black");

        VBox vbox2 = new VBox(10);
        vbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox2.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
                + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
                + "-fx-border-color: black");

        VBox vbox3 = new VBox(20);
        vbox3.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        vbox3.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
                + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
                + "-fx-border-color: black");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Button bt = new Button("Button " + (i+1));
            Button bt2 = new Button("Button " + (i+1)); // unfortunately there´s no "clone" or "copy" method
            Button bt3 = new Button("Button " + (i+1));

            vbox1.getChildren().add(bt);
            vbox2.getChildren().add(bt2);
            vbox3.getChildren().add(bt3);
        }

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox1, vbox2, vbox3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 350, 250); // the hbox is the root node

        primaryStage.setTitle("HBox and VBox Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```